How to modify "Deployed" column in App Catalog
Currently, when I deploy a new version of a webpart. The site automatically get the newest version without having to press the 'Get it' button in site contents. I think this is related to the Deployed column in app catalog. Is there anyway to edit the value of Deployed column or how to prevent automatically update when deploy a new version of a webpart.



Title
App version
Deployed




app1-client-side-solution
0.0.1
Yes


app2-client-side-solution
0.0.1
Yes



Thank you alot.

It's by designed. Once you upload a package to the App catalog, it will show Deployed.
